# Controlling fan speed on H67N-USB3-B3

Tags: fan

I recently got a new computer with a H67N-USB3-B3 motherboard.

When running `sensors-detect`, it doesn't detect the fan controller, only the CPU temp probes. For that reason, running `pwmconfig` returns that no pwm-capable sensor modules are installed.

The fans are running all the time on the machine.

Is there a way I can control the fan speed or even stop them occasionally?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!